# Executing shell scripts that take long time using child process module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax, shell, child-process

Below is my code written to execute a script called mqValidation.sh in UNIX by sending an AJAX request. This spawns a new child process and when the child process exits, it sends a text file response which obviously contains the output of the script. But, the issue I'm facing here is, as the script takes long time to finish, a new child process is being spawned before the first child process exits, which means that the script is getting executed again.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cp = require('child_process');


app.post('/triggerMQ', function(req,res){

ls = cp.spawn('./mqValidation.sh',req.body.envs,{cwd:"./MQValidation"});


ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log("Child process exited");
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/MQValidation/html.txt');
});

});

app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("app listening at port 8000.....");
});
```

Please help!!

Comment: and how *should* it work? The new child process is created again only when you hit the URL more than once, that means everything works as expected

Comment: U mean the request is being sent again by the browser as it did not receive any response

Comment: @smnbbrv u mean the request is being retried by the browser

Answer (score 0):

Increasing timeout on the server side resolved the issue. Looks like after 120 seconds, the browser is sending another request which is triggering the script again.